# Ignore compile errors

Tags: compiling, errors, latexmk

How can I set up a permanent compile loop that keeps trying even when there are errors? I'm using latexmk with a remote compile setup as discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/173914/dropbox-latex-automated-pdf-compile) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1398/dropbox-latex-compiling-automation). However, if I save a document with a bug (either a legitimate bug, or I save it before closing a tag), then latexmk halts. Any suggests how I can have it pause, try again, and keep trying again, for ever and ever?

Comment: Use the `-halt-on-error` option in your latex command. So in `bash` I would write something like `while true; do latex -halt-on-error filename.tex; sleep 5; done`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's `\batchmode`, which will disable terminal output and pretend you just pressed enter on every error message, but it won't save you from infinite loops. (There's also `\nonstopmode`, which I believe does the same with terminal output.)

There are usually corresponding command line switches, `--interaction=batchmode` or `--batchmode`