# How to disable the prompt on error?

Tags: errors, compiling

When `pdflatex` can't compile a file, it drops me to a prompt. I've never used it and always try to get away from there as quickly as possible, usually generating a `q.log` file in the process.

Is there any way to avoid this behavior and let `pdflatex` drop back to command-line on error?

Comment: Perhaps the answers to this question: [Ignore compile errors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5644/ignore-compile-errors) will help.

Comment: @Alan: Thanks. `-halt-on-error` (your link) and `-interaction=nonstopmode` (Martin Scharrer) seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yes, `-halt-on-error` *exits on error*. Exactly what I'm after. Ignoring or not printing errors is not helpful. Especially when make then thinks everything's up to date. I've never used the interactive thing. Imo shouldn't be default.

Comment: I don't believe I've ever had a meaningful interaction with latex when it has halted on an error. I'm sure there is much I could do, but I always `^d`, modify source, and compile again.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use the `-interaction=nonstopmode` command line argument or the `\nonstopmode` macro to disable stopping on errors.

Example: `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode your.tex` (note the `-interaction` flag *before* the filenames).

Answer (score 10):

```
-interaction <mode>
    Starts the so-called interaction mode, which can be specified as
    batchmode, nonstopmode, scrollmode or errorstopmode. The meaning of
    these options is the same as for that of the corresponding \commands.
```

Which is to say that placing `\batchmode` as the first line in your document would have the same effect.

If you didn’t know about those commands, here’s what they do (from [TeX usage tips](http://www.volkerschatz.com/tex/ttips.html)):

> The modes make TeX behave in the following way:
>
> - `errorstopmode` stops on all errors, whether they are about errors in the
>     source code or non-existent files.
> - `scrollmode` doesn't stop on errors in the source but requests input when a
>     more serious error like like a missing file occurs.
> - In the somewhat misnamed `nonstopmode`, TeX does not request input after
>     serious errors but stops altogether.
> - `batchmode` prevents all output in addition to that (intended for use in
>     automated scripts). In all cases, all errors are written to the log file
>     (yourtexfile.log).

Answer (score 9):

To drop back to the command line on the first error like gcc (or other compilers do), use:

```
pdflatex -halt-on-error yourfile.tex
```

Comment: Took this information from the comments on the question.  This is what simply worked for me.