# Installing LaTeX in a server

Tags: installing, distributions

I need to run LaTeX in a server using an explorer (just like Safari or Chrome). The thing is that I can't find a software that allows me to do that, as, for example, R Studio does (they have the program in their web page). Is that possible?

I do not need much security. The thing is that I need to run it from my iPad, for example thru safari. The reason why I'm using a server is because I use a lot of packages and most of the computers take a lot of time processing the document.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @Rico, mathjax only does render the fonts, or better, it interprets some LaTeX commands and use some different font to show the text. I guess that the OP wants to run pdflatex on the server, for example, to insert some `tex` text on the field and compile to obtain the pdf.

Comment: Maybe you can use [TeXlive.js](https://github.com/manuels/texlive.js)

Comment: It might be useful to give more details of the workflow that needs to be supported. Are we talking users upload `.tex` files and get a PDF back or something more complex? Do you need the server to run as a service (daemon)? Any particular security requirements?

Comment: It's also interesting whether you can act as root or not

Comment: Based on the edit, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49946/setting-up-your-own-latex-compile-server might be of interest, or perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8021/is-there-a-latex-distribution-running-on-ipad.

Comment: I think I'd consider [Prompt](http://panic.com/prompt/) on the iPad, and [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) on the server if you're prone to losing your network connection. Add whatever text-mode editor you like for editing code (Emacs or XEmacs with [AUCTeX](http://www.gnu.org/s/auctex/), or [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sf.net/).

Comment: If you're going online anyway you could have a look at this question: [Compiling documents online](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3/compiling-documents-online)

Answer (score 3):

Google provides a Latex distribution based on an old version of Texlive (TL 2009) that allows the service to be made accessible by their CLSI (Common Latex Service Interface).  The system can be downloaded from Google Code; [the project's installation documentation](https://code.google.com/p/common-latex-service-interface/wiki/InstallAndConfig) provides a step-by-step guide.

You can use the service through its webform (you need Apache and PHP installed).  There might be a CLSI client app somewherefor the IPad, which would probably be nicer to use; if so, links appreciated, as always, in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering why not use a local environment that includes both typesetting and a syntax-highlighting editor?.

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the Texpad developers.)

May I suggest looking at Texpad for iOS (http://texpadapp.com/ios). We have local typesetter that we believe is currently the most completely LaTeX system on iOS with advanced fonts, beamer and TikZ. We also have a full package manager that practically delivers the whole of texlive to you:

http://support.texpadapp.com/kb/typesetting-ios/latex-bundle-manager-on-texpad-ios

Like the OS X version, the app will open multi-file latex projects starting from the root and also allow you to search across files. There's autocomplete in the iPad version, synctax highlighting, dropbox support. Full list of features is online at http://texpadapp.com/ios .

Comment: This does not answer the question, in my opinion. The question is about installing LaTeX on a server.

Comment: Understand your point and apologies if my answer sounded self-publicising. One of our main motivation for spending a year figuring out & rewriting large parts of the tex engine for iOS was to remove the need of a cloud server. Having recently written our own PhD theses, we knew that was a grossly poor solution. If it hadn't been so, people across the academic world wouldn't be putting up with downloading 4GB of latex distributions on their desktops. So, although it wasn't the literal answer for the question being posed, it was certainly the correct answer in my view to the 'problem' in hand.